# How to decompile luajit binary bytecode?

Tags: android, lua, bytecode, decompiler, luajit

I have an Android app which runs luajit byte code for some thinks, and code is called by library "libluajit.so".
How to read luajit byte code, and how to convert it into normal lua script to make some changes, or to see some procedures from the code.
I was trying some lua decompilers, but each of them says that code is not lua byte code, and I know that yes.
It is lua binary file, and please help me how to get file content.
Link is here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z2W34hoIFjyvk3pKtxqvdh8TAmfbtm__/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please list out your code using the proper tag. Do not provide a file to download. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The code cannot be listed because it's binary and encrypted.

Comment: The file is encrypted. From looking at the file in a hex editor, what stands out is that the distribution of values is odd and many bytes have value `AF`. This looks like a XOR cypher. You can use for example [CyberChef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=XOR%28%7B'option':'Hex','string':'af'%7D,'',false%29) to decrypt it, with key `AF`. The resulting file looks like a valid LJBC file, but I still had trouble decompiling it - after the first few instructions, every decompiler (and even LjAsmEditor) would show garbage. Maybe there are additional protection mechanisms in place.

Comment: OK, can we try bin from the previous version of app? This file begins with "LJ". Link is here: <https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pyGswo4zj_kx-5VC-0YDwVjCEx4akyYc/view?usp=sharing>